# Missing data when querying administrative regions in the Overpass API

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I would like to get the administrative regions for Somalia.

I tried two queries:

```
area["ISO3166-2"~"SO-"];
rel[admin_level=5](area);
out geom;
```

and:

```
rel["ISO3166-2"~"SO-"]
   [admin_level=5]
   [type=boundary]
   [boundary=administrative];
out geom;
```

The queries work but both results are missing the Sahil region in Somaliland, circled below in green:

[image]

The data definitely exists in the OSM database and it is tagged as admin_level 5: https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/13316065

Any idea why the query does not return the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea why the query does not return the data?

Because https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/13316065 doesn't have a
[`ISO3166-2`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:ISO3166-2) tag.

Comment: Amazing! With a keen eye for details, one truth prevails :-)

I fixed it by querying like this: `area["name:en"~"Somaliland"];`